# If $a,b,c$ are the roots of $x^3-px+q=0$, then what is the determinant of the given matrix in $a, b, c$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> If $a,b,c$ are the roots of $x^3-px+q=0$, then what is the determinant of 
>   $$
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     a & b & c \\
>     b & c & a \\
>     c & a & b \\
>     \end{pmatrix} \,\,?
> $$
>   (A) $p^2+6q \quad$
>   (B) $1 \quad$
>   (C) $p \quad$
>   (D) $0 \quad$

In this equation given we have product of eigenvalues given as $-q$ and we know product of eigenvalues is determinant then why isn't the determinant is $-q$?

Comment: compute the determinant in a first step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this equation given we have product of eigenvalues given as $−q$ and we know product of eigenvalues is determinant then why isn't the determinant is $−q$?

The statement you're thinking of is that *the product of eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ is equal (up to sign, depending on parity) to the constant term of its characteristic polynomial $p_A$*.

In this case, however, the given matrix, though constructed from the roots $a, b, c$ of the characteristic polynomial, doesn't have the property that its eigenvalues are $a, b, c$, and therefore the above general fact does not apply.

On the other hand, using, e.g., cofactor expansion gives that the determinant of the given matrix is
$$\det \pmatrix{a&b&c\\b&c&a\\c&a&b} = 3 a b c - (a^3 + b^3 + c^3).$$
On the other hand, writing the cubic polynomial as $$x^3 - p x + q = (x - a)(x - b)(x - c),$$ expanding, and comparing like terms recovers a special case of [Vieta's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas):
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
 0 &=& - (a + b + c) \\
-p &=& bc + ca + ab \\
 q &=& -a b c 
\end{array} .$$
Manipulating these lets us write both terms of the expression $3 a b c - (a^3 + b^3 + c^3)$ for the determinant as polynomials in $p, q$. These manipulations give special cases of [Newton's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Comment: I think you are the only one here who gave the correct answer. Actually i had doubt in that eigen value portion. Thanks i totally forgot about characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @user459687 I'm glad you found the answer useful. (As far as I can see, though, the other answers here do give correct methods for computing the determinant itself, even if that wasn't your main question.)

Comment: Of course i know how to compute determinant and substitute values. I was looking for something else and you told me that. May be i didn't explain my problem in good manner during writing the question.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Using Sarrus, one gets 
$$\det(A)=3abc-a^3-b^3-c^3.$$

Using that $a,b,c$ solve $x^3-px+q=0$ you can conclude.

Comment: Can't use eigen values here? From that equation of roots?

Comment: May be it is, I didn't check... but this is a very simple method.

Comment: You don't _have_ to use Sarrus (which I had to google, by the way, since it wasn't a name I had heard). Most reasonable rules for calculating the determinant will give you that expression, or one very much like it.

Comment: @Arthur : I don't think that your comment is very constructive. By the way, did I said that you "have to" use Sarrus ? It just a way (among many other way) to compute the determinant.

Comment: I think the fact that I had to do a search to understand everything in your answer detracts from its overall value. The way you wrote it, it seems like Sarrus is a special trick that you can apply in situations like this (see, for instance, the way the other short answer specifically mentions Vieta). After having googled it I can see that one can indeed use any technique one finds comfortable, but your answer would've been better if it hadn't misled me. Since you didn't find it constructive, you are welcome to consider it a clarification to other readers who so not know what Sarrus is.

Answer (score 2):

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\ b&c&a \\ c&a&b\end{pmatrix}=(a+b+c)\det\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\ b&c&a \\ c&a&b\end{pmatrix}=0$$
since $a+b+c=0$.

Comment: Wow very nice sir. Sadly it didn't click my mind when i was doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Determinant = $3abc-(a^3+b^3+c^3)$

By Vieta's theorem,
$$a+b+c=0\\ab+bc+ca=-p\\abc=-q\text.$$